# jQuery .click() ajax problems in IE8 and under

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I have this weird problem of a function bound to a click event on a radio input firing off before the radio button becomes selected when triggered by another click event. Sounds a bit confusing when put that way so here's a look at the code:

```
<div class="side">
    <input type="radio" id="100" value="100" name="radiogroup" style="display:none;" />
    <label for="100">
        <img src="" />
        <span>Description</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Most browsers support the clicking of a label to trigger the selection of a radio input, but of course IE doesn't. Because of this I'm using conditional classes on my html, e.g.

```
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 ie8" lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <![endif]-->
```

This allows easy creation of IE specific javascript. In this case I need to simulate a click on the radio input when the label is clicked, which I do like this:

```
$(".lt-ie9 .side label").bind("click", function() {
    $(this).siblings("input").click();
});
```

Everything works fine up to this point. The problem comes in when I try to insert an AJAX call when a radio input gets clicked, like this:

```
$("input[name=radiogroup]").bind("click", function() {
    //some ajax call referencing which radio option is selected.
});
```

The problem I'm having is that the ajax method is getting fired off before the radio input has actually been switched to the most current selection. So for example if I have multiple radio inputs, say with id/values of "100", "101", "102", etc. If I click on 100, then I click on 101, the ajax call is using the value of 100 rather than the most recently clicked value of 101. Anyone know why this is happening? It seems to me like that ajax method shouldn't be called until the newest radio button has been checked. Hope this all makes sense.

Comment: have u tried using change instead of click?

Comment: onclick happens before onchange, after onchange is when the value property gets updated. Logically, what it is currently doing makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It kind of worked by switching the bind to 'change' instead of 'click', however IE was still having problems. I solved this by calling $(this).siblings("input").click().change();

Answer (score 0):

IE will not work with the display:none on the radio to fire the click on the label; however, you can get around that (similar to what you have) by triggering the change event on the hidden element (or the click event); You have an issue with the markup as well.

I modified your markup to fix an ID that cannot start with a number and added slightly modified code - a bit more modular than your solution perhaps?

```
<div class="side">
    <input type="radio" id="my100" value="100" name="radiogroup" style="display:none;" />
    <label id='my100label' for="my100">
        <img src="" />
        <span>Description</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

And the code, using the new id:

```
$('.side').on('click','#my100label',function(){
  $('#my100').prop('checked',true).trigger('change');
});
$('#my100').on('change',function(){
  alert('Howdy I am:'+ $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

NOTE: You can remove the `.prop()` code and simply trigger the "click" event however, the FIRST time inside the change/click for the radio the prop will be false (not yet changed/clicked) - be sure to be aware of that if you go that route.  It is better to monitor the change event in this case as you will not be able to manually "click" the element and it will need to be changed/clicked using code due to its hidden nature - and if inside a form, it will not submit.

NOTE: Tested this code using jQuery 1.9.1 and IE8 here: http://jsbin.com/ocisul/1/edit